# How may I run rsync with "parallel" from the local system to fetch files in parallel?

Tags: rsync, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to `rsync` approx 10 TB of data from a remote system to the local machine, and I want to use the `parallel` utility for multi-thread execution.
I want to trigger the `rsync` from the local server. Can someone please suggest how I may do this?

Comment: The bottleneck with rsync is often IO requests. Running multiple rsyncs in parallel will only make this worse.

Comment: `parallel` and `xargs` might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate on why this does not work:

```
seq -w 0 99 | parallel rsync -Havessh fooserver:src/*{}.png destdir/
```

From https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Parallelizing-rsync

Answer (score 0):

This has worked well for me:

cat /tmp/dir_list.txt | parallel --will-cite -j6 time rsync -ahrzp  user@:/{} /